# Scrollbar won't hide or move in Worksheet_Activate()

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Worksheet_Activate()` sub in the code for a sheet that resizes the sheet every time it's activated, and hides the scrollbars. For some incomprehensible reason, when I'm running it as part of another sub (using "`Sheets("MENU").Activate`") the "`ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False`" doesn't work!! As in, the vertical scrollbar stays visible.

Worse, when I set the "`.width`" later, the scrollbar doesn't move with it! So I end up with a floating scrollbar 20 or so pixels off the side of the application window.

Worse even still, when I put breaks in the code to walk through it, it works fine.

I'm stumped on this one.

Here's the relevant code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate() 

With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayHeadings = False
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False    ' <-- this guy right here...
End With

With Application
    .WindowState = xlNormal ' can't resize maximized!
    .Left = 100 ' as soon as I do this, things go sideways
    .Width = 570
    .Top = 50
    .Height = 230
End With
End Sub
```

I thought maybe it was a problem with the code executing too fast, so I put in a couple of pauses with

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
```

But that doesn't seem to help.

I can hack my way around it by putting another "`ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False`" in the sub prior to activating the window, but then I'm avoiding the problem, not fixing it.

Comment: I can't replicate this in Excel 2013. You might want to try a `DoEvents` between the 2 `With` blocks.